# File is not part of FileSystem Error in reading XML file in Springboot

Tags: java, json, linux, xml, spring-boot

I am reading Xml file in springboot placed in src/main/resources folder. It is working fine in local but after creating JAR file and deploying on linux server I am getting "File is not part of file system" error. After deployment on linux server system is not able to find the file.

File Read Code:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("appSettings.xml");
    File file = resource.getFile();
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    appSettings settings = xmlMapper.readValue(file, appSettings.class);
    Map<String,String> cGMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(add a : settings.getAdd()){
        String val=ConvertToString(a.getValue());
        cGMap.put(a.getKey(),val);
    }
    return cGMap;
```

I am able to read the file and getting file content in my local. But after creating JAR and deploying on linux server system is not getting file path and saying file is not part of file system.
Can anyone please suggest me what I am missing and what I need to do to make this file path available on remote server.

Regards
Prabahsh Mishta

Comment: Hello! Did you tried adding file path in your application.properties file? I think it happens when you write file path manually, but not in configuration file.

Comment: Your local tests are not using the jar, so classpath resources can be accessed as a `File`. A resource loaded from a jar in classpath won't have a valid `File` equivalent. You should always test locally with the same jars that you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is likely due to the difference in file paths between your local environment and the Linux server.

Since your file is inside the jar, I would suggest to read it as InputStream rather than File.

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("appSettings.xml");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
appSettings settings = xmlMapper.readValue(inputStream, appSettings.class);

//rest of your code.
```

Alternatively you can refer your file using @Value annotation as below:

```
@Value("classpath:appSettings.xml")
Resource resourceFile;
```

it's more convenient than previous version.

Please check [samples](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access) on how you can read files from classpath.